# Firebase dynamic links - custom suffix

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I made a simple python script to generate firebase dynamic links for my app using POST API
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest

However, in web UI I can set custom link address (i.e. example.app.goo.gl/customlinkname), while using API address seems to be always auto-generated.

Is there such a feature using POST API?

I tried to set "option": CUSTOM with customSuffix parameter, however response was that option CUSTOM is not supported.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope -- this feature is not available using the REST or Client SDKs. Only for Dynamic Links that you create using the Firebase Console.

Comment: Is this coming from Google officially? Because this is exposed on a few other libraries according to documentation on the internet https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/firebasedynamiclinks/v1#Suffix

Comment: Same here. @Todd Kerpelman I think the definitiveness in your answer minus pointing to a link probably means you're a Google representative. Where can I request this feature?

Comment: Is there any method this can be acheived for current versions?

Comment: Be great to have this. "Unsupported Suffix option CUSTOM" [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]

Comment: I do not understand why this is not possible !!!!

Comment: You can request this feature here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?visit_id=637066788649418383-3154538132&rd=1

Answer (score 2):

Don't trust naysayers. I know it's too late, but because I've struggled so much searching for solution I'm uploading working solution I've found recently.

Use library firebase-dynamic-links-generator by Sufiyan Shaikh (see https://pypi.org/project/firebase-dynamic-links-generator/#description). It allows you to create custom suffix that you'll be able to see in your Firebase console.

Note: To import this file use `from firebase_dynamic_link import GenerateFirebaseDynamicLink` instead of `from firebase_dynamic_link_generator ...`